# How to handle listbox(asp control) in Jmeter

Tags: listbox, jmeter

I have a listbox control and dynamically populated values within that. On selecting a value from listbox and clicking a button, the selected value from listbox will be set in one or more textboxes.

In Jmeter, the selected list box value is not set and button action doesnt proceed further.It leads to error page.

Could someone please help me in handling this.

Attaching the screenshots for the same

[Listbox with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOeK8.png)

[Selected value set in the sampler during recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka9bI.png)

Comment: did you try to check "Encode?" option?

Comment: As far as i know JMeter only deals with requests. Does not matter what you did on page or how values are filled in boxes. It does not record those actions. It ONLY monitors the network traffic and records the request sent from your browser.

Comment: Hi I tried the Encode option but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you need to look the request that browser sends in this case (using Developer Tools or Firebug or alike) and compare it to request sent by JMeter. Something is missing from JMeter request, or is not (formatted) right.